# AWS EC2 Instance Hacked

Tags: amazon-ec2

One of my EC2 instances was hacked a few days ago.

I tried logging in via SSH to the server, but I couldn't connect. I am the only one with access to the private key, and I keep it in a safe place.

Luckily, I had a backup of everything and was able to move the web app to a new instance quite fast.

My concern right now is that I don't know how my instance was hacked in the first place.

Why can't I log in via SSH using my private key? I would assume that the private key stored on the server can't be (easily) deleted.

Is there a way I can find out how the hacker gained access to the instance? Perhaps a log file that would point me in the right direction.

Should I attach the EBS volume in question to a new instance and see what's on it or what are my options in this case?

Right now, it seems I have to access at all to the hacked instance.

Thank you!

Comment: Something does not make sense.. The private key is not on the instance, it has only the public key. The private key is with you on ur local machine. Did that get compromised, are you sharing it with someone?.

Comment: Just had this happen to my EC2 instance where I am using it to host a discord bot. I was alerted to the issue by a slew of posts in my discord server from "Dabbah" with a repeating set of unwanted images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might have logged into your machine via password. In ssh config, check the value of: PasswordAuthentication. If it is set to yes, then users can login to the instance remotely via password. Check /var/log/secure for any remote logins. It will show up all logins (password or key based).

If someone logged in as 'root', they can modify the ssh keys.

Comment: How can I check this if I can't connect to the instance? FTP or SSH does not work anymore. I am locked out of the instance.

Comment: as @Karen B mentioned, take an EBS snapshot of the root volume and attach it (create volume out of it) to a new ec2 instance. Mount the volume and look at the log files

Answer (score 1):

@Krishna Kumar R is correct about the hacker probably changing the ssh keys.

Next steps:

Security concerns (*do these now*!):

1. Stop the instance, but don't terminate yet
2. Revoke/expire any sensitive credentials that were stored on the instance, including passwords and keys for other sites and services.  Everything stored on that instance should be considered compromised.

Post-mortem

1. Take an EBS snapshot of the instance's root volume (assuming that's where logs are stored)
2. Make a new volume from the snapshot and attach to a (non-production) instance
3. Mount and start reading logs. If this is a linux host and you have port 22 open in the firewall, I'd start with `/<mount-point>/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are unable to login to the machine does *not* mean that it has been "hacked". It could be due to a configuration change on the instance, or the instance might have changed IP address after a stop/start.

Do a search on StackOverflow for standard solutions to problems connecting to an instance and see if you can connect (eg recheck IP address, check security group, turn on `ssh -v` debugging, check network connectivity & VPC settings, view `Get System Log`, etc).

Worst case, yes, you could:

- Stop the instance
- Detach the EBS volume
- Attach the EBS volume to another EC2 instance
- Access the content of the EBS volume